# Term frequency given a fixed field value in Lucene 5.3

Tags: java, lucene

What would be the best way to calculate term frequency given a fixed field value in Lucene 5.3?

I would like to build some data charts showing how often a term shows in my documents, which have a date field assigned (numeric field: yyyyMMdd). I'll make line charts using a framework like ChartJS.

Is it better to make a normal Lucene query and count the hits or is there a more efficient way to do it? (I've looked into PostingsEnum, but I didn't find an easy way to set date field value)

I have something like this:

```
public List<LocalDate> getDataFrequencyOpc(String text) {
    List<LocalDate> result = new ArrayList<LocalDate>();
    IndexReader indexReader = DirectoryReader.open(directory);
    PostingsEnum postingsEnum = MultiFields.getTermDocsEnum(indexReader, "content", new BytesRef("text"));
    int i;
    while((i = postingsEnum.nextDoc()) != PostingsEnum.NO_MORE_DOCS) {
        Document doc = indexReader.document(i);
        LocalDate auxDate = LocalDate.parse(doc.getField("date").numericValue().toString());
        result.add(auxDate);
    }
    return result;
}
```

But I don't like it because I think it would be really costly to order data to make the charts (as I don't have my dates filtered).

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**:

I hope I can clarify a bit the question...

Input: "text" I want to search in the field "content". "date1, date2" period of time I accept in the field "date".

Output: number of documents that match the text and their date is between both the dates (alternatively I could manage with one date and iterate).

The easy way and the only solution I can think of right now is building my query as I usually do, which I think it's a waste because I only want the number of hits.

Comment: In that case, running a query is indeed the correct approach. As far as it being a waste, keep in mind, just running a query doesn't incur the cost of retrieving document contents. Pretty much the entire cost is in determining the documents that match the query.

Comment: Then I guess that should be the answer. How do I deal with this? I'd feel bad were I to answer my own question. :|

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total term frequency (that is, frequency across the whole index) for a given term from [`IndexReader.totalTermFreq`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#totalTermFreq-org.apache.lucene.index.Term-):

```
myReader.totalTermFreq(new Term("date", myDateValue));
```

Comment: Thanks! But I want to do that with more than one restriction.